# Pycaret MlFlow authentication

Tags: google-colaboratory, mlflow, pycaret, dagshub

How can I use `log_environment = True` in Pycaret `setup` with

`import os import mlflow mlflow.set_tracking_uri("https://dagshub.com/BexTuychiev/pet_pawpularity.mlflow") os.environ["MLFLOW_TRACKING_USERNAME"] = "MLFLOW_TRACKING_USERNAME" os.environ["MLFLOW_TRACKING_PASSWORD"] = "MLFLOW_TRACKING_PASSWORD"`

Without getting  `RestException: INTERNAL_ERROR: Response: {'error': 'not found'}`

Answer (score 0):

In case others may run into this challege. When using DAGsHub, the tentative solution is creating a experiment in mlflow ui first.

In my situation the experiment name was called default. So, I had to make sure it ws reflected as **experiment_name = 'Default'** in the **setup()**.

The wierd thing that I experienced  was it would not create new experiment name using the pycaret **setup()** and I recieved the error mentioned in the above post.